# MediaRecorder records in video/webm format instead of audio/webm

Tags: amazon-s3, audio, blob, mediarecorder, getusermedia

In ReactJS I am using MediaRecorder to record my audio from microphone by below code:

```
getUserMedia({ audio: true })
      .then(stream => {
        this.stream = stream;
        const mime = ['audio/wav', 'audio/mpeg', 'audio/webm', 'audio/ogg']
          .filter(MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported)[0];
        this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
          mimeType: mime
        });
        console.log('MIME: ', mime);
        this.mediaRecorder.start();
        const audioChunks = [];
        this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', event => {
          audioChunks.push(event.data);
        });

        this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', () => {
          const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, {
            type: mime});
       });
      }).catch(error => { });
```

In my console I am getting `MIME:  audio/webm`. I am storing this blob to S3 bucket, but when I download this file then the type of the file changes to `WebM video (video/webm)`.

Any idea why is this treating as video file even after giving the correct mime type. I tried botht in Chrome and Firebox browser.

Comment: Did you find a answer to this?

Comment: Tried passing { video: false, audio: true } as constraints to getUserMedia()?